# All audios should be played after combing using ffmpeg. But there is only audio for the first part

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, merge, overlay

This code is combining 3 mp4 files using ffmpeg command. Each file has audio. 
After combining, I can listen audio for only first part. 
How can I solve this problem?

===========================================================================

```
ffmpeg -y -i "tmp/titled-0c33a83dc70534c67f66.mp4" -i "tmp/titled-1c2fc9a95e644ab135a3.mp4" -i "tmp/titled-73c3fb1a3ea435cacdd2.mp4" -i "logo/logo.png"  -filter_complex "
nullsrc=s=1280x720[bg];
[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+0/TB[v0];
[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+4.039/TB[v1];
[2:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+8.078/TB[v2];
[bg][v0]overlay=x='if(lte(t,4.039),0,min(0,-w*min(1,max(0,0.98*(t-4.039)^2))))':y=0,trim=duration=13.145[bg];
[bg][v1]overlay=x='if(gte(t,8.078),-w*min(1,max(0,0.98*(t-8.078)^2)),max(0,1280*(1-min(1,max(0,0.69*(atan(8*(t-4.039)^2.7)))))))':y=0[bg];
[bg][v2]overlay=x='max(0,1280*(1-min(1,max(0,0.69*(atan(8*(t-8.078)^2.7))))))':y=0"
-y -vcodec h264 -crf 13 -acodec aac -strict -2 "out.mp4"
```

Comment: You didn't tell `ffmpeg` what you wanted to do with the audio or which one(s) to use, so the default [stream selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) behavior chose one audio stream from one of the inputs. What do you want to do with the audio? I'm guessing you want the audio from each video to play only when that video is visible within your "slideshow".

Comment: yes, you have understood correct, Could you help me?

Comment: Show the **complete** log from your command. There are several methods to do this. Some are easier than others. Answer depends on input file info and your ffmpeg version. The log will provide this required information.